# Making a WebBrowser control in wpf read-only?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to make the wpf webbroswer control read-only in the sense that I still want to be able to give users the ability to copy texts off of textfield etc but I dont want them to be ableto click button or submit forms.
I wrapped the web browser control in a wpf user control. When I set the IsEnabled proerty to false, it works i.e the webbroswer control is disabled but the user cannot select text from the page...

Answer (score 4):

You can handle the WebBrowser's [Navigating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigating.aspx) event and cancel it so that the user can't navigate to another page.

```
void myBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;      
}
```